# How do I resolve a looping configuration issue on my broadband modem configuration?

Tags: windows-vista, networking, internet

My problem is that I just had cable broadband Internet installed in my house and I tried hooking up the broadband Internet from the modem to my notebook but the broadband was not connecting to the Internet. The ethernet light keeps blinking.

I contacted the technicians about 8-10 times followed and repeated their instructions about 10 times with no success. I called them again and they told me that the IP address was LOOPING or something similar to that.

Is it possible to correct this problem myself, or is it an issue on my ISPs end?

**My setup:**

I am using Windows Vista x64.

I have a direct cable Internet connection from the modem to the notebook, **no router** is being used.

**Updated with some diagnostic details:**

IP address and Obtain DNS server address are set to automatic.

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ##
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

PPP adapter Juno:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Juno
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 69.44.162.16(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 64.166.49.91
                                       64.166.12.91
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link 5100
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-16-EA-EA-EA-45
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-16-EA-EA-EA-45
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::704f:772c:179e:f862%11(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.248.98(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 15:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 16:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 17:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 18:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 20:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 21:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 23:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 29:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 34:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 35:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 6TO4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 40:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1F5D0389-1887-4C55-B6B1-332674B59
279}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 41:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1F5D0389-1887-4C55-B6B1-332674B59
049}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 42:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1F5D0389-1887-4C55-B6B1-332674B59
B67}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 44:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : isatap.{1F5D0389-1887-4C55-B6B1-332674B59
B67}
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 45:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #23
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 46:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter #11
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:4511:a24a::1952:a50e(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:4316::c154:3571
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 64.136.44.74
                                       64.136.52.74
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: Please give us the response of "ipconfig" from the cmd prompt

Comment: open a command prompt, type IPCONFIG /ALL and press ENTER. please post the results or a screenshot.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range/1106943#1106943

Answer (score 2):

Alrighty

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on your keyboard.
2. Type `cmd` and press Enter.
3. Type `ipconfig`.
4. Look for `Wireless LAN Adapter` or `Ethernet Adapter` (none of the others matter for this exercise).
5. Pick out the numbers next to the `Default Gateway`.
6. Type `ping *0.0.0.0*` (**replacing 0.0.0.0 with the numbers found in the above step**).
7. Look for the ping statistics at the end. If `sent = 4` and `received = 4`, your connection to your modem/router is fine. If not there is some sort of problem between your computer and BB equipment.

Please edit your question if you need to add any additional info

Edit: Looking better

Looks like we've got some sort of equipment failure.

Try step 6 again. Type the following instead:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

Report back with results

Edit 2: If you cannot ping 127.0.0.1, this is fundamental. Try uninstalling/disabling any security software and trying again.

Edit 3: We're clearly looking at a problem with your computer (so you can rule out ISP). The next steps are to re-install TCP/IP, reseat the NIC, then replace the NIC.

Prior to the above, though, I'd turn off IPv6, I've had some success with that

Answer (score 1):

The blinking light might be the normal operation of your network card.
Can you give more information about your setup: can you ping the router (normally 192.168.0.1)?
Look in Network Connections : what's the status of your Local Area Connection?
Go in the Properties of Local Area Connection, then click on Internet Protocol version 4 then again Properties: what values do you have for Obtain an IP address and Obtain DNS server address?

Comment: Just to remark that I couldn't ping your DNS servers. They might perhaps only be reachable from your ISP, which seems to be AT&T, so try pinging then yourselves. If they don't ping, maybe you should try OpenDNS at http://www.opendns.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Dude we are going to need a lot more info that that. For starters, are you getting lights on the modem? Are you going though a router? Did you try to hook your computer -- laptop up to the modem directly? For that matter, is any of the computers working?

A tech savy friend may be able to help 1000 time better than anyone here because connectivity issues often takes looking around... At least, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

> Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . :
>   169.254.248.98

you have a problem with your DHCP server, the 169.x.x.x address is assigned by the operating system if it can't get an IP address from the DHCP server (e.g. router, cable modem)

Comment: How do I fix this problem if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you power cycled the modem at some point?  Depending on how the cable modem provider has their system configured, the cable modem may lock on to the MAC address of a device, and only issue IPs to that MAC.  It needs to have the power pulled before connecting to another device.  Another thing to try - almost all cable modems nowadays have built in DHCP servers that kick in when there is a lack of signal.  Try unscrewing the coax, cycle the modem and see if the computer gets a different IP address.  If it does, then there is likely an issue on the provider end.  If it doesn't it is most likely hardware.  Also try removing AC and battery power from the laptop for about 30 seconds and power it back up.  See the below post as far as why that may help.

[Ethernet Port Troubles](https://superuser.com/questions/27229/ethernet-port-troubles/27266#27266)